(Illustrator) White space when saving EPS file when printed. Effect>Rasterization Issue?
What does the "Add "0.5" around Object" do in the Effect>Rasterize prompt box? Does it effect the Rasterization or is it more like a background border?
It seems like when I Effect>rasterize my art work and save my EPS file the EPS has space exceeding the artwork and artboard even though I've checked if there's any hidden objects or clipping masks that might effect it and there's none. And it seems to happen only when I Effect>rasterize.
So im wondering if the "Add "0.5" around Object" is just adding a border or dead space around the objects?

Ive tested a few different saving options. Checking the Clipping mask Box, setting the 0.5 to 0 and it seems saving as long as the number is saved to 0 there is no white space. So that measurement does indeed just create a border around the object.
Also noticed I had brought in an object from a previously rasterized file and that was saved at 0.5 so that was what was creating the white space as well.
It was easily fixed by going into the Appearance window and deleting the previous Rasterize Effect and double checking the current rasterize Effect was set to 0.
Yay technology.

